# Why elasticsearch indexing work so weirdly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch, python-requests

I was trying to index some data with elastic search, and faced a strange behavior.

If my code is:

```
import requests
#data = {'key': 'value'}
data = {'v': 'pf'}
#data = generate_document()
print(data)
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
r = requests.post('http://localhost:9200/qa/_doc', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
```

I get `201` as response code.

But if I have `data = {'va': 'pf'}`, for some reason I get `400` status code.

Why do these weird things happen?

Basically I want to randomly generate `data` and index it. Most of the time it throws `400`. But regular things like `data = {"key": "value"}` works.

Comment: I strongly suggest using [elasticsearch python client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/index.html) along with [elasticsearch dsl](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) when working with elastic from python.

Comment: @vlizana basically I was trying to use locust for load testing es instance, that's why using standard rest API to collect URL specific stat.

Comment: Even though you get response code `201` data will be indexed. List all the indexed docs from the index

Comment: @bigbounty, I don't get it. `201` generally means `CREATED`, so it will indeed index the document. My question is about `400`, which means `BAD REQUEST`. My question was why I am getting bad request, even if both my request are almost identical?

Comment: What is the setting of the indexes setting attribute:  mappings.dynamic  

If its strict it might be throwing an error because of that setting.   if you want to be able to randomly add fields make sure its set to true

Comment: Thanks guys. As @vlizana suggested, I thought, let's see if the python client can figure out the issue with the same input. And I got it finally. The error says: `elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'Limit of total fields [1000] in index [qa] has been exceeded')` I actually generated random keys, and hence the max key limit reached. I should think about it. Need to tweak my code a bit so that it can use limited number of keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the status code 400 could have multiple causes:

1. could be caused my the mappings.dynamic set to strict
2. could be caused by exceeding 1000 fields in the index.

There may be others.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah I found the solution and were to write an answer. But your answer is good enough. In my case, the number `2` was the cause of the error. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import requests
#data = {'key': 'value'}
data = {'v': 'pf'}
#data = generate_document()
print(data)
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
r = requests.post('http://localhost:9200/qa/_doc', json=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Same result, `{'v': 'pf'}` works, but `{'va': 'pf'}` doesn't.